# HIbernate: insert many to one: error Column cannot be null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Ho everyone, i have a problem when insert entity many to one.
problem: I wana insert a new record: staffId, type, reason. But table Records and employee have relationship many to one, so i dont know how to insert in this table with prop of **class DTO** is staffId or Employee employee, and how can i insert that. Tks so much!

code below:

**employee entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STAFF")
public class Employee {
@Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
private Long departmentId;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Department department;
```

**Records entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Records", catalog = "Assignment")
public class Records implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private Employee Employee;
private boolean type;
private String reason;
private Date date;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "StaffId", nullable = false)
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return this.Employee;
```

**RecordDTO**\

> In controller, i dont know which class to use, Form or DTO
>       public class RecordDto {

```
  /*=====================================================================================================
 *===== PRIVATE PROPERTIES                                                                        =====
 *=====================================================================================================*/

/**
 * trunglq_department.ID
 */
private Long id;

/**
 * trunglq_department.Employee
 */
private Employee Employee;

/**
 * trunglq_department.type
 */
private boolean type;

/**
 * trunglq_department.reason
 */
private String reason;

/**
 * trunglq_department.date
 */
private Date date;
```

**RecordForm**

```
public class RecordForm {

/*=====================================================================================================
 *===== PRIVATE PROPERTIES                                                                        =====
 *=====================================================================================================*/

/**
 * trunglq_department.ID
 */
private Long id;

/**
 * trunglq_department.Employee
 */
private int staffId;

/**
 * trunglq_department.type
 */
private boolean type;

/**
 * trunglq_department.reason
 */
private String reason;

/**
 * trunglq_department.date
 */
private Date date;
```

**repository**

```
@Override
public Long insert(Records record) {
    record.setDate(new Date());
    return (Long)super.insert(record);
}
```

**service**

```
@Override
public Long create(RecordForm recordForm) {
    recordForm.setStaffId(9);
    Records record = (Records) DataTransformUtil.transform(recordForm, Records.class);
    return (Long)recordRepository.insert(record);
}
```

**Controller**

> In controller, i dont know which class to use, Form or DTO

```
 @PostMapping("/create")
public String index(Model model, @ModelAttribute("formRecord") RecordForm recordForm,HttpServletRequest request) {
    recordService.create(recordForm);
    return "/employee/index";
}
```

**JSP**

> jsp is modal, i get data in table when click on a row.
>   in this, data include: staffId, type, reason.
>   Error code is null StaffId.

```
form:form modelAttribute="formRecord" action="record/create"
                method="POST">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        Ghi nhận nhân viên có ID:
                            <label class="idStaff"
                            style="font-size: 20px"></label>
                    </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->

                <div class="modal-body">
                        <form:hidden path="staffId" class="idStaff"/>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <form:radiobutton path="type" class="custom-control-input"
                            id="customRadio" name="radioRecord" value="0" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio">Achievement</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <form:radiobutton path="type" class="custom-control-input"
                            id="customRadio2" name="radioRecord" value="1" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Mistake</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reason">Reason:</label>
                        <form:textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"
                            path="reason" />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form:form>
```

**Error code**

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'StaffId' cannot be null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965162/spring-reading-multiple-user-roles-from-list-of-strings-or-enums

Answer (score 0):

Your staff pojo is missing staffId(PK). Also why do you have department id if you already have a Department variable?

Your table might have staff_id, department_id, staff_name etc, so for many to one, you just need to add the foreign key reference and in pojos, you have to specific the joincolumn to be department_id. similar to the Record entity you have.

Comment: staffId  is column Id bro :<

Comment: Yes, a entity must have a primary key. In order to join Department from your Employee,for your Employee entity, you don't need department_id, and for join, just apply same way you join Employee on Record Entity.